# Insert new rows into table but copy data from another row in the table

Tags: sql, ingres

I have a table within my ingres db with the following values for example

```
grd    gsd    Name   Location
112    04     Joe    Test
```

I want to create a new row with the same data copied but the "grd" value changed to a new value like below

```
grd    gsd    Name   Location
113    04     Joe    Test
```

How can I achieve this in an optimised sql statement?

Comment: Do you _only_ want to update a record with certain values?  Or, do you want to update the whole table?  What is the logic behind the new value for the `grd` column?

Comment: There are multiple records within the table that need to be changed but the only value changing is the "grd" we are moving to a new "grd" value with the same data so it just needs to be copied

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO your_table (grd, gsd, Name, Location)
    SELECT
        grd,--or change it here as you need (for example replacing with value 113)
        gsd,
        Name,
        Location
    FROM your_table
    --WHERE some condition (e.g. grd = 112)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
insert into MyTable(field1, field2, "113")
select field1, field2, grd from MyTable where grd = "112";
```